# onclick kiosk mode to another opened window

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js

I'm working on a NW.js app and one of the requirements is that when a new window is opened `window.open` then there must be a button to enable it in kiosk mode since this opened window will be extended to another screen for display. I can't seem to do it. I don't know how I can target this new window which I opened. Even in the browser I can't figure it out. I spent two days on this and still.

I tried using this but with no success:

```
openWindowBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    slavePanelWindow = window.open('url', 'SlavePanel', "height=400,width=700");
    setInterval(function(){gui.Window.get().enterKioskMode();}, 5000);
});
```

I thought if I dragged the new opened window quickly to the extended display then waited without selecting any other window then this new opened one would enter the kiosk mode.

P.S. I can't open the new window directly to kiosk mode. There must be a button which does this.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Open a new window and enable kiosk.
nw.Window.open("url", {
    "width": 700,
    "height": 400
}, function(win) {
    win.on('loaded', function() {
        win.enterKioskMode();
    })
});
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to expound on the code in your answer. Tell about how it works or what exactly you are doing. This helps newer developers understand exactly what is going on.